# From Honey Harbour up to Bayfield Inlet, where can you attain/reach Georgian Bay's shore only by car, without any boat?

Tags: ontario, georgian-bay

Please limit suggestions to the demarcated area below.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "access or contact"? It seems that the town of Parry Sound has a variety of marina facilities, and I imagine there's at least one boat ramp there somewhere. Also, a quick look around Google Earth reveals a large number of small marinas with access available by car. And Killbear Park seems to have a lot of places where you can drive nearly up to the beach. Which should be fine unless you want to actually drive your car into the lake.

Comment: I downvoted this question because its premise seems to contradict easily available information (as pointed out by @GregHewgill).  Can you please edit the question to clarify what kind of access you want and/or what research you have done thus far?

Comment: I don't quite get the question either. Since pretty much the entire shoreline is reachable by road, it is just a matter of picking a place with public access (i.e. not someone's private cottage) and whatever facilities you're looking for. I'll suggest the Wasauksing Marina or Woods Bay Marine since I've been there, but there are a surfeit of places I haven't been. And I'm also not sure what it is that Parry Sound lacks.

Comment: @GregHewgill I mean  "access or contact" by car to the shore of Georgian Bay, where you can step out of your car and then touch the waters of Georgian Bay. Parry Sound is an inlet and so is not precisely Georgian Bay.